# How do I get my simple object to conform to NSManagedObject and NSCoding in Swift?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nscoding

I have two objects I am storing in Core Data with swift. `List` is one object, and `Item` is another.

Here's the `List` class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class List:NSManagedObject {
    /* Remember, any @NSMananged variables added or changed here 
     needs to be reflected in Model */
    @NSManaged var name:String
    @NSManaged var items: [Item]
}
```

And here is the `Item` class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Item:NSManagedObject, NSCoding {
    /* Remember, any @NSMananged variables added or changed here
     needs to be reflected in Model */
    @NSManaged var title:String
    @NSManaged var address:String
    @NSManaged var notes:String
    @NSManaged var quantity:Int32
    
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(title, forKey: "title")
        aCoder.encodeObject(address, forKey: "add")
        aCoder.encodeObject(notes, forKey: "notes")
        aCoder.encodeInt32(quantity, forKey: "qty")
    }
    
    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        title = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("title") as! String
        address = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("add") as! String
        notes = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("notes") as! String
        quantity = aDecoder.decodeInt32ForKey("qty") 
    }
}
```

I have read the apple documentation about `NSManagedObject`, `NSObject` and `NSCoding` and it may as well be in a foreign language.

If I don't implement any of the funtions, it doesn't conform to `NSCoding`. If I implement `encodeWithCoder()` and required `init()` it conforms to `NSCoding`, but then it wants me to add the other `init(entity...)` for conformance with `NSManagedObject`. What do I have to do with this funtion?

Comment: why are you trying to make it conform to `NSCoding`?

Comment: @Wain I was under the impression it had to conform to NSCoding so I could store it in the items:[Item] in the List class. Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong.  If you set up your core data model so that list has a many to one relationship to item then will all be taken care of for you

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to conform to `NSCoding`. Core Data will store all of the attributes you have defined in the model without `NSCoding` and you don't need to implement anything to put things in an array.

BUT!!

If you have set your attribute in core data as `transformable` then that explains where you're heading, you would need to implement `NSCoding`, but it can't then also be a managed object. This would also be the wrong approach as you should be using a relationship in the model.

Comment: Thanks Wain. So don't put it as Transformable in the model (which is what I have done). If its not transformable, what do I set the array type to? String?

Comment: delete the attribute and create a bi-directional relationship instead, then regenerate your model classes - you'd use a transformable attribute for things which can't be / don't make sense to be entities. the relationship will appear as a set in the code.

Comment: Now I'm getting really lost. Do I then delete the attribute in the class List or leave it there? If I delete it, how then do I associate an item with a specific list?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to clean up the mess:

- Delete both `NSManagedObject` subclasses.
- Set a relationship from `List` to `Item` (one to many) and a reverse relationship from `Item` to `List` in the Core Data Model.
- Recreate the `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

That's it. Now Core Data will manage everything for you. No `NSCoding` needed.

Edit:

To get an ordered `items` array for a `list` object for example sorted by `quantity` write

```
let items = (list.items.allObjects as! [Item]).sort{ $0.quantity < $1.quantity }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Now I have an NSSet, which as far as I can tell is unorderd. How do I populate tableviewcells with it, and when one is selected/deleted, how do I ensure it's the right one.

Comment: You can perform a fetch with a specific sort descriptor or you can use `(list.items.allObjects as! [Item]).sort{ $0.quantity < $1.quantity  }` which returns an array and sorts the items by `quantity` for example. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I can see how that works. I'm in the process of fixing up all the now-broken code to deal with the new array. I appreciate the help.